# How to mass update parent from child list view

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller-extension

I need help with a controller extension to retrieve and update parent records from a list view. We have   a child object called Patient_Session__c that has a lookup to parent called Patient_c and want to use a   visualforce page to update the parent records in  mass edit mode from a list view of the child records.    Here's the extension I am using

```
public with sharing class updatePatientInfo {
    public Patient_Session__c pgn;
    public Patient__c patient; 
    public updatePatientInfo(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        this.pgn = (Patient_Session__c)controller.getRecord();
        this.patient = [SELECT Id,Name,Patient_Description__c,A_1__c,A_Frequency__c,B_1__c,B1_Frequency__c,B2_Frequency__c,C_1__c,C1_Frequency__c,C2_Frequency__c,D_1__c,D1_Frequency__c,D2_Frequency__c,X__c FROM Patient__c WHERE ID = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')];
    }
    public PageReference saveRecord() {
            update patient;
    update pgn;  
        return null;
    }
 }
```

When I try to save the visualforce page I get this error

> "Error: Unknown constructor 'updatePatientInfo.updatePatientInfo()"

I am new to apex so any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

From your code:

```
public updatePatientInfo(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
```

and your error:

> "Error: Unknown constructor 'updatePatientInfo.updatePatientInfo()"

I can say the following:

you don't have `updatePatientInfo` constructor that takes no arguments. Your only constructor needs 1 argument of type `ApexPages.StandardController`